# Dockerfile FROM for rhel images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel

I would like to create a Dockefile as below

```
FROM <rhel6/7>

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN addgroup redis && useradd -g redis -ms /bin/bash redi

RUN mkdir /data && chown redis:redis /data
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /data

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /data

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["/usr/software/rats/bedrock/bin/python2.7", "/data/test_redis.py"]
```

what do i replace `FROM <rhel6/7>` with?

Comment: "and it doesnt work" --- is not a problem description, really.

Comment: @zerkms nitpicking the question is not constructive

Comment: "it does not work" is what not constructive. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: @zerkms where do you see "it does not work" in the edits

Comment: @zerkms please refrain yourself from adding comments if it not intended to actually answer the question. your initial comment isnt even asking for clarification (it's just downplaying the Q). i think we would agree that it would be more valuable for your time to be spent at else where than on this Q

Comment: It surprises me somebody as snarky as you cannot use google search https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_containers/using_red_hat_base_container_images_standard_and_minimal

Comment: And so that you learned something "docker rhel 7 image" <- this google search query answers your "question" exactly.

Comment: @zerkms you must have lots of free time

Comment: I'm not sure how my personality and my personal time is relevant to your question. Please avoid referring to anything that is not directly relevant to your problem. Thank you.

Comment: same to you as you somehow categorized me as "snarky"

Comment: Has your problem not been solved yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the official guide from the Red Hat

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel
```

References:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_containers/using_red_hat_base_container_images_standard_and_minimal#building_container_images_with_standard_base_images

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem too!

1. You can browse from [Red Hat Container Catalog](https://access.redhat.com/containers/) under "Products" section and choose the image you want
2. Most 2 commons right now are
   [RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=images&platform=docker#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7) and [RHEL 7 Atomic](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=overview#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7-atomic) (the new one oriented to host container)
3. In "Get Latest Image" you can choose from different platform from OpenShift to Docker
4. Just type the command given `docker pull registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7-atomic` for example

Everything could have been way easier but you know it's Red Hat...